# pip editable install on read-only filesystem

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

is it possible to do an [editable pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) from a directory located on read-only filesystem? Right now setup tools is trying to write an egg file into the source directory:

```
$ pip install -e /tf/stuff/
Obtaining file:///tf/stuff
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to src/stuff.egg-info/requires.txt
    error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'src/stuff.egg-info/requires.txt'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tf/stuff/
```

The docs say:

> For local projects, the "SomeProject.egg-info" directory is created
>   relative to the project path. This is one advantage over just using
>   setup.py develop, which creates the "egg-info" directly relative the
>   current working directory.

Comment: Hope you are doing it with sudo  access

Comment: Yes, the file system itself is read only.

Comment: I wonder if anybody still has

Answer (score 2):

If you have any writable filesystem in your environment you might be able to do what I did.  I created a symbolic link in my source directory (`src/stuff.egg-info` in your example) that pointed to a location that is writable (perhaps on a different read-write filesystem) and was able to get `pip install -e .` to work.

Comment: This worked for me! Trying to `pip install -e` inside a docker container but also mount in the source code as read-only. It's kinda hackish, but if I create a simlink to e.g. `/tmp/mypkg.egg-info/`, and create an empty directory in the container at that point, then I can pip install -e the read-only `/src/mypkg` dir inside the container.

Comment: The symlink would have to be created before it's mounted, because once mounted it's read-only and the symlink cannot be created. Note that if you're in this situation because of Docker's `RUN --mount`, you can add the `rw` option to make it writeable, and Docker will just discard the writes.